# About GeckoWebBrowser KeyEvent

Tags: vb.net, gecko

I want send keycode to GeckoWebBrowser, the html source as below:

`<input onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 ; event.charCode <= 57" disabled="" id="field1" type="tel" value="" pattern="[0-9]*">`

the VB.NET code:
Dim ev As DomEventArgs = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.CreateEvent("KeyEvents")
Dim curInput As GeckoInputElement
curInput = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("field1")
curInput.Focus()
nsIEventVar.InitKeyEvent(New nsAString("keypress"), True, False, GeckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow, False, False, False, False, Keys.Enter, Keys.NumPad0)
nsIEventVar.InitKeyEvent(New nsAString("keyUp"), True, False, 
GeckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow, False, False, False, False, Keys.Up, Keys.NumPad0)
Xpcom.QueryInterface(Of nsIDOMEventTarget)(curInput.DomObject).DispatchEvent(nsIEventVar)

but unsuccessful send 0 to input control.

Comment: I use:                                                                                                   `Dim Element As GeckoInputElement = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("field1")                 Element1.Click()                                                                      Element1.Focus()                                                                   SendKeys.Send("{Enter}")                                                         Element.Value = str1 `                                                                                           but can not enable input.

Comment: Dim Element1 As GeckoInputElement = GeckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("field1")             Dim Utils As nsIDOMWindowUtils = Xpcom.QueryInterface(Of nsIDOMEventTarget)(Element1.DomObject)
        Using type As nsAString = New nsAString("keypress")
            Utils.SendKeyEvent(type, 0, Keys.NumPad0, 0, False)
        End Using